# I Want to Fetch profit and loss account from tally erp using collection

Tags: collections, tally

Hi i want to fetch tally erp data for profit and loss using collection and i am having hard time to get the method to write collection for the same as it does not have anything available of Profit and loss account. can any one help me with the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Most important thing to run this script successfully Tally and script has to be on same machine

## import pyodbc for odbc operation

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
```

## Connection string will be your Tally server name and port

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=TallyODBC64_9000;SERVER=({local});DRIVER=Tally ODBC Driver64;PORT=9000')
cursor=conn.cursor()
```

## Select command for fetching record, be careful here because Select * might fail while converting to csv as it has limitation of rows

```
Company = cursor.execute("SELECT $Name, $Address, $Website, 
$GUID, $EMail, $StateName, $PINCode, $PhoneNumber, 
$ShowBankDetails FROM Company")
```

## rest is pretty simple

```
columns = [column[0] for column in Company.description]
actual_cols=[s.strip('$') for s in columns]
rows = Company.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows)
df.columns=actual_cols
pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows)
columns=actual_cols
df.to_csv("D:\\Company.csv", index=False)
```